# How to put this program in a loop in java?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;

class token {
public static void main(String args[]){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random number = new Random();

    System.out.println("Do you want to play again(y/n)? ");
    String in = input.nextLine();   

    do{
    int num1,num2,sum;
    num1 = 1+number.nextInt(6);
    num2 = 1+number.nextInt(6);

    sum = num1 + num2;


    System.out.print("Dice 1: "+num1);
    System.out.print("\nDice 2: "+num2);
    System.out.print("\nSum: "+sum);

    if(sum%2==1){
        System.out.println("\nYou have lost 1 token.");
    }else if(sum>10){
        System.out.println("\nYou have won 2 tokens.");
    }else if(sum>11){
        System.out.println("\nYou have won 2 tokens.");
    }else if(sum>12){
        System.out.println("\nYou have won 2 tokens.");
    }else{
        System.out.println("\nYou have won 1 token.");
    }

    System.out.println("Do you want to play again(y/n)? ");
    String in1 = input.nextLine();  
    }while(in == "y");

}
}
```

So I tried to use a do while loop but unfortunately, it does not loop at all.
Sample output:
Do you want to play again(y/n)? 
**y**
Dice 1: 3
Dice 2: 4
Sum: 7
You have lost 1 token.
Do you want to play again(y/n)? 
**y**

I want my program to continuously loop unless the user enters n.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace     `in == "y"` with `in.equals("y")`

and

`String in1 = input.nextLine();` with `in = input.nextLine();`

because you are not up updating value of `in` so if input is "y" for the 1st time it will loop forever, or will run just once otherwise.

Comment: Actually, he should also replace `String in1 = input.nextLine();` with `in = input.nextLine();`.

Answer (score 0):

You should take repeated input in your while loop, and then have a termination condition:

```
String in = input.nextLine();
do {
    /* conditional logic */
    in = input.nextLine();
} while (in.equals("y"));
```

The way you have it you are setting it to a new string every time within the loop, which will cause it to not be used in the next sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
while(in == "y");
```

you should use:

```
while(in.equals("y"));
```

== operator is testing the reference.

equals really checks the contents of the string.

Answer (score 0):

You should use

while(!in.equalsIgnoreCase("n"));